# how can i store all details on login base

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

[image]
This is migration

```
  Schema::create('refunds', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->bigInteger('contact');
        $table->date('requested_at');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is user profile when user click on refund button then store all data of user in another table how its possible?

this is my controller

```
 public function refundstore(Request $request)
{
    
   $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $refund = new Refund(); 

$refund->user_id = $id;
$refund->refund_id = $refund->id; 

$refund->save();
    return view('front.user.profile', compact('user_id', 'refund'));
}
```

This is view

```
 <form action="{{ route('refundstore',Auth::user()->id)}}" method="post">
              @csrf
            <button class="applyRefund mt-2">Apply For Refund</button>
           </form>
```

This is route

```
Route::post('refundstore', ['as' => 'refundstore', 'uses' => 'RefundController@refundstore']);
```

show error like this
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `refunds` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2022-03-05 10:47:01, 2022-03-05 10:47:01))

Comment: If I understood correctly, you try to add the logged in user details to the refund table. Your controller says you have already done this. What problems you are facing now?

Comment: what would be the new table to store the data? i see you are storing the data in the refunds table, what's wrong with it?

Comment: it is right then why show me error like this syntax error, unexpected '$refund' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: yes i try to add loggen in user details to refund table.Shrey

Comment: @Kinnu123, can you please share the photo showing the error?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'sno' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `refunds` (`id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 2022-03-05 10:39:22, 2022-03-05 10:39:22))

Comment: i added semicolon, and it is not syntactical error, i try to all data of authentical user in one click but field show error like this SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'sno' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `refunds` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2022-03-05 10:47:01, 2022-03-05 10:47:01))
..did you get it or not

Comment: i will share migration

Comment: It is same as id

Comment: if i set nullable in database then in table data empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242622/discussion-between-kinnu123-and-medilies).

Comment: it is not require field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user = Auth::user();

$refund = new Refund();
$refund->user_id = $user->id;
$refund->name = $user->name;
$refund->contact = $user->contact;
$refund->requested_at= date("Ymd");
$refund->_token = "1111";

$refund->save();
```

Comment: first i try to understand my question, i created user profile and in user profile one option button apply for refund, whenever user click on refund button users data like name, contact all save in another table.....without form....do you understand

Comment: ok i got your point then you dont have to create form just call the above function on click and and get all the user information using Auth:: do you get my point?

Comment: yes you are right, i want exactly that

Comment: then simply call the function using jquery ajax and you will solve this 100%.

Comment: its not possible through laravel?

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ url("refundstore") }}'">Refund</button> you can do this thanks me later

Comment: why not? i will definitely say thank you for that you give me your valuable time for this topic,  i added which things require    <button type="submit" method="post" onclick="window.location='{{ route("refundstore") }}'">Refund</button>  now error show The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: change route from post to get

Comment: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value now show this error

Comment: In your refund table you are not sending user_id check your code or send me your latest function code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242633/discussion-between-kinnu123-and-waris-abdullah).

Comment: Thank you so much for give your valuable time for this topic, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

First add `type="submit"` in your button

And change your Controller to this code :

```
public function refundstore(Request $request){

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $refund = new Refund();

    $refund->user_id = $user_id;
    $refund->refund_id = $refund->id;

    $refund->save();
    return view('front.user.profile', compact('user_id', 'refund'));
    }
```

You got error on user_id doesnt have default value because your request a wrong data. In your controller you declare `$user_id = Auth::user()->id;` so that `$user_id` will find Auth user id that currently tried to make a refund request, if you wanted to make $id to find the user_id, you have to make a new function. In this case you already make `$user_id = Auth::user()->id;` so you can use `$user_id` instead of `$id` to speed up your time.

Comment: Code is right but i have no any form about refund so i have to all data of user which is authenticated but whenever i try to submit raise this error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `refunds` bcoz of it find name but i have no form, did you understand now